# Как подружить Spring Boot с JSF

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jsf

Разрабатываю небольшой WEB-проект, в котором за сервисный уровень отвечает Spring, а контроллеры и веб-странички сделаны на JSF.

В faces-config.xml определен:

```
    <el-resolver>
        org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver
    </el-resolver>
```

т.е. управляющим контекстом у меня по-идее должен быть контекст спринга.

JSF контроллеры выглядят примерно как-то так:

```
@javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean
@javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped
@Component
public class BookController extends AbstractController<Book> {

@Autowired
private BookService bookService;

//some methods...

}
```

То есть контроллер является одновременно и `Spring bean` и `Managed Bean` и все вроде бы работает нормально, да аннотации `@javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean` и `@javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped` помечены как `Deprecated`. Немного погуглив, выяснилось, что вместо `@ManagedBean` теперь нужно использовать `@Named`, т.е. аннотацию CDI. Попробовал такой вариант, но теперь в поле `bookService` не инжектится соответствующий `Spring bean`, т.е. при инициализации этого контроллера, поле остается просто `null`.

Есть какие-то варианты в данном случае не использовать `Deprecated` аннотации `@ManagedBean` и `SessionScoped`?

Comment: переписать под спринг... я думаю.